# Disabling/Enabling A Network Service/Filter (.NET/C#)

Tags: c#, windows, com

I want to be able to disable a given network filter/service (is this what they are called?) on a particular network interface. For example, given the screenshot below, I want to be able to disable and enable "Npcap Packet Driver (NPCAP)" programmatically. I believe the .NET APIs do not allow for direct manipulation of these stuff, but any other solution (P/Invoke, COM, CLI command, etc.) is also good. I have tried my luck with the `netsh` command, but could not determine how this can be done. Also, COM interop seemed a good solution, but I could not get it to work.

[image: NIC Properties Window]

The following is a snippet of my COM adventure (it makes use of some modified code from [this CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29700/AdapterList)):

```cs
INetCfgComponent? devComponent = this.FindComponent(netCfg, deviceName); // INetCfgGuid.IID_DevClassNet

if (devComponent != null)
{
    INetCfgComponentBindings devComponentBindings = devComponent.QueryInterface<INetCfgComponentBindings>();

    foreach (string serv in servicesToDisable) // for instance, the NPCAP one
    {
        INetCfgComponent? serviceComponent = this.FindServiceComponent(netCfg, serv); // INetCfgGuid.IID_DevClassNetService

        if (serviceComponent != null)
        {
            INetCfgComponentBindings serviceComponentBindings = serviceComponent.QueryInterface<INetCfgComponentBindings>();

            if (serviceComponentBindings.IsBoundTo(devAComponent) == 0) // 0 means bound
            {
                serviceComponentBindings.UnbindFrom(devAComponent); // error 0x8004A024, even when run as administrator
                netCfg.Apply();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As stated in code, I am encountering an errot with message of `0x8004A024` even when the application is run as administrator.

Comment: Did you tried to aquire write lock with `netCfg.AcquireWriteLock`? Remember to release it!

Comment: If you haven't found proper `netsh` commands you should try to use PS [comandlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/disable-netadapterbinding): `Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "VMware*VMnet8" -DisplayName "NPCAP*"`

Comment: @Selvin, I actually hadn't. Now I did and my call to the `AcquireWriteLock` on the `INetCfgLock` interface is giving me the same error (`0x8004A024`). It's totally possible I'm doing something wrong though. I would appreciate if someone can give me a link to a working repo or something.

Comment: @Daemon-5, great! It works just fine. My limited research showed me that this CmdLet is only available on Windows 8+, right?

Comment: @Ali, I suppose it works only on supported  Mcrosoft OS by WMI with [MSFT_NetAdapterBinding class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/hh872343(v=vs.85))